# strange behavior of object freeze

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use Object freeze function in node v13.10.1, however, it behaves remarkably useless! what's the point if I'm not get anything if somebody try to change a frozen attribute? they might think that they've changed it and search for the cause of confusion, exactly like me!

for instance this code does not throw error!! uncanny!

```
const myObj = Object.freeze({
  name: 'alex',
});

myObj.name = 'tom';

console.log(myObj); // it'll show { name: 'alex' }
```

Comment: Are you in strict mode?

Comment: i.e. Add [`"use strict";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) at the top of your script and it will throw an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because by default you’re running your code in [sloppy mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

you should declare [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), so run this one instead to see

```js
'use strict';

const myObj = Object.freeze({ name: 'alex' });
myObj.name = 'tom';
```